# Bundle Seed ID: Team ID vs Existing?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, provisioning, app-id

I'm creating a new explicit app ID because I want to use APNS and I only have the wildcard app ID, e.g. A1B2C3D4E5.*, that Xcode created for me.

For the "Bundle Seed ID (App ID Prefix)," should I "Use your Team ID or select an existing Bundle Seed ID"?

The [iOS Provisioning Portal : Create App ID](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/bundles/add.action) page says:

> If you are creating a suite of applications that will share the same
>   Keychain access, use the same bundle Seed ID for each of your
>   application's App IDs.

What is my Team ID and when should I use it?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using my Team ID (which generated a new Bundle Seed ID). Here was my reasoning (Acani is my app's name.).

> OK. Do I want to use Team ID or existing ID?
>
> I think existing ID.
>
> Why? If you use existing ID, then any app you build will share
>   keychain access with Acani.
>
> So?
>
> So, do you want that?
>
> Well, not really... But, what if I want to make another app. And I
>   want it to share keychain access with Acani? AND, it doesn't need an
>   explicit app ID? Then, I have to create another wildcard app ID for no
>   reason.. Actually, what if Apple does this automatically (I doubt
>   it. [It didn't]).
>
> OK. So, big deal. You'll have three app IDs. Everything will be more
>   organized though. One app ID for development. One for Acani and one
>   for the other app that you want to share Keychain access with Acani.
>
> OK. Sounds good. :)
>
> Are you sure?
>
> No, I'm not sure... but if I keep fretting over it, I'm not going to
>   do anything... I'm just going to sit here...
>
> Well, I want to make sure I make the best choice.
>
> There is no best choice. Also, it doesn't really matter.
>
> I'd say use a new team ID because that's what you're intention is. I
>   mean, you're not intending to share Keychain accesss with any other
>   apps right now. And, in the future, if you are, you create another app
>   ID. It's that simple.
>
> OK. But, why not just use the existing app ID?
>
> Well... You could, but this way, if you want to have developers work
>   and not let them access Acani's Keychain services, you can. :)
>
> OK. Sounds perfect!

Sometimes, if I don't have another person to talk things over with, simply talking to myself in a text editor is comforting... :) #protip